# Execute multiple functions, but stop when an error occured

Tags: c#, events, while-loop, switch-statement

I want to use multiple functions after each other but if something went wrong in the first function the other functions shouldn't be executed. At the moment I'm using a while loop with a switch. Is there a  way to skip the whole while/switch part with something else? Maybe something like an event?

```
while (!ErrorActive && iStep != 3)
{
    switch (iStep)
    {
        case 0:
            DoSomething(); // this can trigger ErrorActive
            iStep = 1;
            break;

        case 1:
            DoSomething2(); // this can trigger ErrorActive
            iStep = 2;
            break;

        case 2:
            DoSomething3(); // this can trigger ErrorActive
            iStep = 3;
            break;
    }
}
```

the DoSomething functions have something like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        //calculate something
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorActive = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to skip the whole while/switch part and replace it with something else (like an event maybe?) or should I always keep something in between each function to check if everything is all right?

Answer (score 1):

Just move the catch one level up:

```
// true if all steps executed, false otherwise
bool DoSteps()
{
   int lastExecutedStep = 0;
   try{
     DoSomething();
     lastExecutedStep = 1;
     DoSomething1();
     lastExecutedStep = 2;
     DoSomething2();
     lastExecutedStep = 3;
   }
   catch( IOException ioex )
   {
      // log IO Exception
   }
   // ... catch more expected exception types

   return (lastExecutedStep == 3);
}

void DoSomething(){
   // NO try/catch here
}
```

Even possible without stepcounter:

```
// true if all steps executed, false otherwise
bool DoSteps()
{
   try{
     DoSomething();
     DoSomething1();
     DoSomething2();
     return true;
   }
   catch( IOException ioex )
   {
      // log IO Exception
   }
   // ... catch more expected exception types

   return false;
}
```

For a more academical approach you may want to explore [Chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: Isn't that bit odd? For example i'm doing some functions to get information from a file
The first Function reads the file, this can fail by IOexception 
The second function needs to convert some values from string to int  which has a different kind of exception.

Than I should have x amount of catches in this try catch. I can do the catch (Exception E) to catch all the exception but that isn't realy gd?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What is feeling odd about this to you?

Comment: And when you actually creat some kind of object out of the file, its odd to say when this object is created you can have an IO exception or conversion exception. Thats why I want to catch it the other way around, Feels more natural for me

Comment: Well, I don't know what feels "natural" to you. Of course, catching `Exception` is a catch-all, which isn't recommended. You should leave it out and catch specific exception types. Mind that creating a try/catch context is expensive. Here, you have only one instead of n. So, that's less overhead. If you have more requirements, you should amend your example in the question.

Comment: What do you mean? They _are_ separate functions. If one throws, execution will continue with the catch block. All code in the try block that is after the throwing one will be skipped.

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong answer comment. This will work but still it feels odd to do a try catch over all my functions. Saying yea if something goes wrong in then execute this.

I mean function B cannot trigger an IOException, but than i need a different catch for that one specific. Giving me a try with for example 5 catches (or even more depending how many type of exceptions can trigger)

Comment: I fail to understand the problem you are having with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209062/discussion-between-bart-and-fildor).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows , why you use so mach code when solution is very simple.

```
if(!ErrorActive){
 DoSomething(); // this can trigger ErrorActive
}

if(!ErrorActive){
 DoSomething1(); // this can trigger ErrorActive
}

if(!ErrorActive){
 DoSomething2(); // this can trigger ErrorActive
}
```

Comment: That's a different kind of approach but I always try to avoid the if if if statements after each other. looks horrible I think :)

Comment: Code will execute line by line. if you catch an exception code execution will skip this if blocks

Comment: I think there is not a simplest way. Switch statement shouldn't be used in this context

Comment: Or you can call DoSomething2() into the DoSomething() function body.In that case you only one check and one call

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `while` loop to a `for` loop and make use of the new `switch` expression syntax to simplify things a bit. Also, have the functions return a success state rather than setting some shared variable:

```
void Run()
{
    var keepRunning = true;

    for(int i = 0; keepRunning; i++)
    {
        keepRunning = i switch
        {
            0 => DoSomething(),
            1 => DoSomething2(),
            2 => DoSomething3(),
            _ => false
        };
    }
}

bool DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool DoSomething2()
{
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool DoSomething3()
{
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, this is new to me.but when I use a function that already returns something else, like it returns an object. I cant return a boolean as well

Comment: @Bart - You can return a tuple `(bool Succeeded, object Result) DoSomething()` if you need to return something as well as the success of the function.